# Find strings in the ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to implement a search on the `ListBox`. The user enters a name in the `TextBox` and only the matching variants remain in the `ListBox`. How do this?

Comment: You must write code for that i guess...Your question is too broad, what do you have problems with? What have you tried?

Comment: if user enters name/text in the textbox then only matching variant will remain then how about the unmatched variant? they will be remove in the listbox forever? or if the user delete the the name/text in the textbox the previous data of listbox will be back?

Comment: You could store the full list in the Tag and upon the TextChanged event creaste a new Items array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented. You may need to modify my implementation but this does work.

Add the following variable to the class:

```
private readonly ListBox.ObjectCollection _originalListCollection;
```

Then using the constructor we initialise this variable with the data that is currently within the listbox:

```
 public FrmStatus()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     _originalListCollection = listBox1.Items;
 }
```

Then we add a `KeyUp` value to the textbox and that method will look like the following:

```
  private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      var matching = (from object i in _originalListCollection where i.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text) select i).ToList();
      listBox1.DataSource = matching;
  }
```

Now adding the information to the Designer.cs file:

```
   this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 28);
   this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
   this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
   this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
   this.textBox1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyUp); //important

   this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
   this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
   "dave",
   "john",
   "eric",
   "jospeh",
   "bob",
   "harry"});
   this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 28);
   this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
   this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 95);
   this.listBox1.TabIndex = 1;
```

And it works.

[image]

Comment: And what if the data in the ListBox is added by the user. Presses Button and opens OpenFileDialog?

Comment: `I want to implement a search on the ListBox. The user enters a name in the TextBox and only the matching variants remain in the ListBox. How do this?` that is what was asked.

Comment: `private readonly ListBox.ObjectCollection _originalListCollection` - What to do with these? Where to insert?

Comment: Between  `public partial class FrmName : Form` and your constructor.

Comment: Everything is working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Have a List or Array of your items, and when User searches, only display result in ListBox, else display all entries.

Comment: It's a *Model/View separation* principle: have a model (all possible items) and UI (`ListBox`) which displays a filtered subset of the model